# Library thrown exceptions

Tags: java, android

I have project as a "library" which does HttpCommunication. I post data into it and receive response. Lib's method can throw several exceptions which I want catch in the hosted app, but somehow I can catch only general Exception instead of specific once.

Library method code:

```
 public byte[] execute(String entityStr) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, 
        ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    ...
    // some code that can throw mentioned exceptions
}
```

Hosted class:

```
try {

    byte[] response = httpClient.execute(profile);
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

code above compiles, but code below does not.

```
try {

    byte[] response = httpClient.execute(profile);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
}
```

Exception objects marked as errors, messages say

Unreachable catch block for UnsupportedEncodingException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.

Hosted class is an Activity. Communication done in AsyncTask class.
If anybody knows what's wrong with it, explain me please.

Comment: Without more details it will be difficult to help; always try cleaning and rebuilding. If they're not runtime exceptions, and you're calling the method you think you are, should work fine. (Might even be fine w/ RTEs too.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Post your comment as answer. Simply cleaning projects helped.

Comment: :) don't say, it drives insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to clean and rebuild--if you're calling the method you think you are, and the signature is as shown, it pretty much has to work.